# implement `do.call` with `call`

Tags: r, do.call

I was taking the exercise from [advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#calls),which is to implement `do.call`,I was able to come up with the `as.call` version,but when I tried to implement with `call`, things seem a little bit confused.

Here is my code:

`as.call` version:

```
do.call2 <- function(what, args) {
  eval(as.call(c(as.name(what),args)))
}
```

which seems to work with the examples in `do.call` doc:

```
tmp <- expand.grid(letters[1:2], 1:3, c("+", "-"))
do.call2("paste", c(tmp, sep = ""))
[1] "a1+" "b1+" "a2+" "b2+" "a3+" "b3+" "a1-" "b1-" "a2-" "b2-" "a3-" "b3-"
```

but when I tried to use `call`, I could not get things right:

```
do.call3 <- function(what,args) {
  cc <- call(what,args)
  eval(cc)
}

do.call3("paste", c(tmp, sep = ""))
[1] "c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)" "c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)"
[3] "c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)" ""
```

here `args` is list of arguments.  I understand that maybe I need to unpack arguments from `args`, but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: To pass `...` as a "list" you could just use `do.call`: `do.call(call, c(what, args))`. If you want to avoid using `do.call`, you could, say, create `cc = call(what)` and assign the arguments iteratively -- somethineg like `for(i in seq_along(args)) cc[[i + 1]] = args[[i]]`. Are you trying to achieve something specific or just as an exercise?